# Node http module error when requesting a .org domain

Tags: node.js

When I use the http module to GET a .org domain I get a 400 response. (Tried with google.org so it's not a server error.) Is this normal behavior?

```
var http = require('http');
http.get("google.org", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " +     res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Added my code. It's just the example from the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code issues the following HTTP request:

```
GET google.org HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

It's your local machine that's responding with a 400 (since the request is indeed invalid).  This happens because [internally](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.5/lib/http.js#L1788), node uses the [url module](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) to parse the string you pass to `http.get`.  url sees the string *google.org* as a relative path.

```
url.parse('google.org');

{ protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: 'google.org',
  path: 'google.org',
  href: 'google.org' }
```

Since your string parses to a null hostname, node [defaults](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.5/lib/http.js#L1314) to using localhost.

Try using a fully-qualified URL.

```
var http = require('http');
http.get("http://google.org", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " +     res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Ok that works for google but it doesn't work for this site:

`var http = require('http');
 http.get("http://isitup.org/", function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
 });`

Does the http module works differently than a regular browser GET request?

Comment: Completely different issue.  You'll notice the error for that site is 403 (Forbidden).  That site's [TOS](http://isitup.org/static/txt/terms.txt) say "*Any client (browser or bot) must provide an accurate and appropriate user agent description when using isitup and it's api.*"  Node doesn't send a UA unless you specify one.